# Angular no me carga correctamente los botones de bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, angular

Buenas  estoy intentando poner estos botones de la pagina oficial de bootstrap en mi app de **Angular** : 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/ , en concreto los botones de tipo **Outline buttons**. 
Lo estoy intentando en un `button` pero no me lo hace correctamente, no tiene los efectos de cambiar el **background** cuando le pasas el raton por encima ni nada, simplemente se ve como un **boton** gris sin vida.

He instalado **boostrap** y **jquery** :

```
npm i bootstrap@3 jquery --save
```

Despues me he dirigido al fichero `angular.json` y he añadido los **scripts y estilos** :

```
  "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ],
```

Y aqui es donde lo **implemento:**

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between"> 

    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
        <a class="btn btn-outline-success" [routerLink]="['/inicio_sesion']" >Iniciar Sesion</a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Success</button>
    </div>   
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
       <a class="btn btn-light" [routerLink]="['/registro']" >Registrarse</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Estas leyendo la documentación de `bootstrap 4` e instalando la __versión 3__ `npm install bootstrap@3 --save`, para solucionarlo elimina la instalación de boostrap 3 que tienes con `npm remove bootstrap --save` e instala la ultima versión con `npm i bootstrap --save` eso te instalara la versión 4.x

Comment: Muchas gracias me lo solucionastes. No me habia dado cuenta.

Comment: Hola, te sugiero que no uses JQuery si estás usando Angular. Sé que Bootstrap depende de JQuery, sin embargo hay un Framework de Bootstrap diseñado específicamente para el uso con Angular. Puedes darle una mirada en [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home). Saludos

Comment: ah perfecto, no sabia de su exostencia, tambien esta angular material, cual crees ques mejor? Muchas gracias. Un saludo